# MySQL: CONVERT_TZ function is not working with field value as argument

Tags: mysql, timezone

I'm working on an app that involves users (teachers) making scheduled lessons. As users of the app could potentially be from around the world the user table has a 'timezone' field, with a default value of 'Australia/Victoria'. The lesson table has a 'starttime' field, which records a DATETIME for the start of a lesson in UTC time. The creator of a lesson is identified by an 'ownerId' field, which refers to an id in the user table.
Now, what I want to do is convert the UTC starttime to the user's timezone as part of a select query.

If I run this:

`SELECT l.starttime, u.timezone, CONVERT_TZ(l.starttime,"UTC",u.timezone) AS userstart FROM lesson l JOIN user u ON l.ownerId = u.id`

I get a result of:

`2022-09-29 09:05:00 | Australia/Victoria | NULL`

Yet if i change the third argument of the CONVERT_TZ function call to a string literal like so:

`SELECT l.starttime, u.timezone, CONVERT_TZ(l.starttime,"UTC","Australia/Victoria") AS userstart FROM lesson l JOIN user u ON l.ownerId = u.id`

I get this:

`2022-09-29 09:05:00 | Australia/Victoria | 2022-09-29 19:05:00`

Why would this be?

Comment: Provide sample source data (as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO) which allows to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Pay attention - the source time and the time processed by the function is the same whereas destination timezone is not UTC... I think that you have no populated the timezones info into your server. Check the data in `mysql.time_zone%` tables. Read [MySQL Server Time Zone Support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html).

Comment: @Akina I have populated those tables, albeit using the data available at dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html rather than the recommended mysql_tzinfo_to_sql command (as I temporarily lack terminal access). If you check again the output time is not the same as the source - it is 10 hours ahead. Granted, given daylight savings it should be 11 hours ahead, so the provided data is flawed. But this doesn't change the fact that the CONVERT_TZ function is behaving differently given a string literal argument than it is with a field value that is by all appearances the same as said string literal.